# Error while adding a new remote repository in JFrog's Artifactory

Tags: artifactory

I have requested for a trial version of JFrog Artifactory and trying to a new remote repository via the admin UI.

For example, I am adding the https://jcenter.bintray.com/ but I am getting an error saying "Error parsing json body" in UI.

[image]

```
2019-05-28 15:03:28,714 [http-nio-8081-exec-10] [ERROR] (o.a.r.c.e.JsonMappingExceptionMapper:23) - Error parsing json body
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.lang.Integer from String value 'admin': not a valid Integer value
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@133a043d; line: 1, column: 400] (through reference chain: org.artifactory.ui.rest.model.admin.configuration.repository.remote.RemoteRepositoryConfigModel["typeSpecific"]->org.artifactory.ui.rest.model.admin.configuration.repository.typespecific.MavenTypeSpecificConfigModel["maxUniqueSnapshots"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.weirdStringException(StdDeserializationContext.java:243)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer._parseInteger(StdDeserializer.java:321)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(StdDeserializer.java:818)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer$IntegerDeserializer.deserialize(StdDeserializer.java:805)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:600)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:92)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.AbstractDeserializer.deserializeWithType(AbstractDeserializer.java:52)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:297)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:414)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:600)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.jsontype.impl.AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.deserializeTypedFromObject(AsPropertyTypeDeserializer.java:92)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeWithType(BeanDeserializer.java:664)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializerProvider$WrappedDeserializer.deserialize(StdDeserializerProvider.java:461)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2704)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1315)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider.readFrom(JacksonJsonProvider.java:419)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest.getEntity(ContainerRequest.java:490)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.EntityParamDispatchProvider$EntityInjectable.getValue(EntityParamDispatchProvider.java:123)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.inject.InjectableValuesProvider.getInjectableValues(InjectableValuesProvider.java:86)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$EntityParamInInvoker.getParams(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:153)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:203)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:558)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:733)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.execute(RepoFilter.java:183)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RepoFilter.doFilter(RepoFilter.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.useAuthentication(AccessFilter.java:433)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilterInternal(AccessFilter.java:215)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.AccessFilter.doFilter(AccessFilter.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.RequestFilter.doFilter(RequestFilter.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryCsrfFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryCsrfFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:164)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:62)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryFilter.doFilter(ArtifactoryFilter.java:124)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve.invoke(RewriteValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here and is authentication required inorder to connect to any remote repo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the field `Max Unique Snapshot` (righthand side of the screenshot you pasted), you've entered an incorrect value. Right now it shows the value `admin` and it should be either an integer or a blank value.

To answer your second question, authentication isn't required to set up JCenter as a remote repository.

Comment: No worries! Feel free to accept the answer and help others too